# google map "a is null" on main.js (line 1121)

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

I'm loading markers in from XML. I have the map initiate at `$(document).ready()` and on ajax complete. I have researched this issue and see majority of the time it happens due to loading map before document ready.So why am I getting it?

when i console.log() in the code below, I receive the complete array, but the map does not show the complete same information.

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var myMarkers = new Array;  

        $.ajax({
        url: "tire-banks.xml",
        dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
                                var xml;    
                                if (typeof data == "string") {
                                   xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                                  // xml.async = false;
                                   xml.loadXML(data);
                                } else {
                                   xml = data;
                                }

                                $(xml).find("location").each(function(){
                                    var locAddress = $(this).find("city").text() + "," + $(this).find("state").text() ;
                                    var cc = $(this).find("cc").text();
                                    var bcc; 
                                    if ($(this).find("bcc")){ 
                                        bcc = $(this).find("bcc").text();
                                        }else{
                                        bcc = " - ";
                                        }
                                    var vendor =$(this).find("vendor").text();
                                    var hours = $(this).find("hours").text();
                                    var HTMLString =  "<div><h3>" + locAddress + "</h3>Vendor: " + vendor + "<br />CC#: " + cc + "<br />Bulk CC#: " + bcc + "<br />Hours: " + hours + "</div>" ;

                                    myMarkers.push({ address: locAddress, html: HTMLString});   
                                });

                                },//END SUCCSESS
        error: function(){
        },
        complete: function(){
            console.log(myMarkers);//returns correct information
            $("#map").gMap({ markers: myMarkers, address: "United States", zoom: 4 });//incomplete data and generates a is null error in firebug
        }
    });//END AJAX CALL
    });
```

Comment: wrap it up with a setTimeout and see if it works that way... :)

Comment: yeah, added a 5 second timeout around drawing the map and it did nothing. good idea though.

Comment: how about `myMarkers`  it does not seem to be a global variable, unless you have not included some other code :) just after/before `doc...ready()...` you should have `var myMarkers;`

Comment: My Marker is defined as an Array, I think you didn't see it because i always forget to edit my codes tabs and it pushes everything to the right... Sorry.

Comment: This might be another reason its just a gut feeling, maybe your complete method is called, before your success has finished gathering all the information, test it by putting everything on `complete` at the bottom of your `success`

Comment: I don't think this is the case, unless jquery's documentation is incorrect.It states that complete fires after success and error callbacks are executed.I'm starting to believe that Gmap was just not inteaded to be used this way.

Answer (score 5):

The only time I've received this error is if the div that you are calling the map function on does not exist on the page.

Answer (score -1):

This error usually happens when you have a javascript error in your own code.  Nothing obvious leaps out from what you've provided here, except:

```
var myMarkers = new Array;
```

really?  Should be either

```
var myMarkers = new Array();
```

or (preferred)

```
var myMarkers = [];
```

Comment: `new X;` is the equivalent of `new X();` in JavaScript.

Comment: Indeed it works.  But it's not best practice (e.g. JSLint reports it as an error)